# sencha cmd: Failed to find any files for

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-cmd

I'm getting following error when i execute `sencha app build`

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any  files for extjs-build\app\app\Application.js::ClassRequire::Object
```

`extjs-build\app\app\Application.js` looks like

```
Ext.define('PM.app.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    requires: [
        'PM.Object'
    ]
}
```

A file for class `PM.Object` exists. The path is: `extjs-build\app\Object.js` and extends Ext.Object with some extra functions:

```
PM.Object = Ext.apply(Ext.Object, {
    ...: function() {}
}
```

The `extjs-build\.sencha\app\sencha.cfg` file:

```
# The path(s) to application javascript sources (comma separated)
app.classpath=${app.dir}/app
```

My Directory looks like:

```
 /extjs-build/
    .sencha/
    app/
        app/
            Application.js
        data/
            SomeStore.js
        app.js
        Object.js
    ext/
        src/
```

I'm running `sencha app build` from `/extjs-build/`

`Ext.Loader` handles the issue correct (`/extjs-build/app/app.js`)

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    paths: {
        'PM': './extjs-build/app'
    }
});
Ext.application('PM.app.Application');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding an empty

```
Ext.define('PM.Object', {
});
```

in file `extjs-build/app/Object.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PM.Object` path (**extjs-build\app**) is outside the build directory of you app (**extjs-build\app\app**)

I suspect you are running `sencha app build` in **extjs-build\app** which means the compiler will look for js files in **extjs-build\app\app**\  (this is because app.classpath=${app.dir}/app)

In your sencha.cfg you can change the classpath. Or move that file into the extjs-build/app/app directory.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. I added my directory listing above. When I move `/extjs-build/app/Object.js` to `extjs-build/app/app/Object.js` Ext.Loader doesn't work